# Android studio : UnsupportedOperationException: Operation is not supported > for read-only collection

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio 3.3.2 
Each time I open my project a message appear : Indexing paused due to batch update.

An error is catch by the IDE :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation is not supported for read-only collection
    at kotlin.collections.EmptyList.add(Collections.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProviderUtil.addBeforeRunTaskToConfig(MakeBeforeRunTaskProviderUtil.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProviderUtil.fixConfigurationsMissingBeforeRunTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProviderUtil.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.FixAndroidRunConfigurationsAction.actionPerformed(FixAndroidRunConfigurationsAction.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:255)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:272)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.lambda$null$2(ActionManagerImpl.java:1356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.lambda$tryToExecuteNow$3(ActionManagerImpl.java:1313)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.lambda$doWhenFocusSettlesDown$2(FocusManagerImpl.java:199)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:3094)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.ifFocusEventsInTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:189)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.executeWhenAllFocusEventsLeftTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.tryToExecuteNow(ActionManagerImpl.java:1312)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.lambda$tryToExecute$1(ActionManagerImpl.java:1297)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.tryToExecute(ActionManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.FixAndroidRunConfigurationsAction.executeAction(FixAndroidRunConfigurationsAction.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.FixAndroidRunConfigurationsAction.perform(FixAndroidRunConfigurationsAction.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.RunConfigurationChecker.lambda$ensureRunConfigsInvokeBuild$0(RunConfigurationChecker.java:70)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:817)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:758)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:394)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I must go to File>Invalid cache/restart to solve the problem. 
Anybody know how to fix it with invalid cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to re-import your project with the new Android studio version.

Also try to invalidate cache and restart.

```
File > Invalidate Cache & Restart > Just Restart
```

If this solution doesn't work, try to just press the play button in the right of the message. It happened to me a lot of times.